# timestamp insert to sql is giving me error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, timestamp

timestamp insert to sql is giving me error :

SQLException: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'Date' at row 1
SQLState: 22001
VendorError: 0

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~this is how it looks like in java:~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
String sql = "INSERT into complaint (ComplaintID,Date) VALUES" + "(?,?)";   
GetCurrentTimeStamp stamp = new GetCurrentTimeStamp();  
PreparedStatement rss = con.prepareStatement(sql);
rss.setInt(1,newComplaint.getComplaintID());
rss.setTimestamp(2,stamp.getTimeStamp());
newComplaint.setMsgResponse(MessageManager.msgResponse.SUCCESS);
rss.executeUpdate();
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~this is GetCurrentTimeStamp class:~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;



public class GetCurrentTimeStamp 
{
    private  java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();

    public Timestamp getTimeStamp(){
    return new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());
    }
}
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~this is the Mysql code:~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
CREATE TABLE `complaint`
 (
  `ComplaintID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  `Date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`ComplaintID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=41 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

please help!!!! thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Your SQLState is saying it is a character string that is too long.
This happens when assigning a `date/time/timestamp` value to a host variable that is
not big enough.

The method doc for one version of setTimestamp:

```
setTimestamp(int parameterIndex, Timestamp x, Calendar cal)
```

Example using UTC:

```
stmt.setTimestamp(1, t, Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")))
```

Where *1* being the index, *t* being the timestamp object, and *Calendar* getting the timezone.

Comment: looks like you're right
tried doing this:
CREATE TABLE `complaint`
 (
  `ComplaintID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  `Date` timestamp (45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`ComplaintID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=41 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

and i got error :Error Code: 1426. Too big precision 45 specified for column 'Date'. Maximum is 6.

but i could insert in Mysql :
INSERT INTO `complaint` VALUES (10,'1980-02-10 22:00:01')
without any problems and i used this timestamp already in java so im confused...

Comment: @user3574121 Edited in some info for ya ;)

Answer (score 0):

i've solved my problem, these are the changes i made:

```
String sql = "INSERT into complaint (ComplaintID,Date) VALUES" + "(?,?)";   
PreparedStatement rss = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    rss.setInt(1,newComplaint.getComplaintID());
    SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");//dd/MM/yyyy
    java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
    Date now = new Date();
    String strDate = sdfDate.format(now);
    Timestamp complainDate= Timestamp.valueOf(strDate);
    rss.setTimestamp(2, complainDate);
    rss.executeUpdate();
```